# JavaScript: opacity works in opera but not IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have used the following script for images and it appears to work fine; yet in Internet Explorer, the text is not fading out as it should. Any ideas?

```
 <td colspan="5" ID='links'>
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#" id="a" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Apie įmonę</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="b" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Naujienos</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="c" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Kainynai</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="d" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Aktyvaus laisvalaikio priemonės</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="e" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Servisas</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="f" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Akcijos</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="g" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Karjera</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="h" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Galerija</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="i" onmouseover="over(this)" onmouseout="out()">Naudota technika</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
<script>
var ba = new Array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i");


function over(from){
var value = 5; 

for(i=0;i<ba.length;i++){

    if(from.id==ba[i])
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.MozOpacity = value/10;
        document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.opacity = value/10;
        document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*10 + ')';

    }
}
}
function out(){
var value = 10;

for(i=0;i<ba.length;i++){

document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.MozOpacity = value/10;
document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.opacity = value/10;
document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + value*10 + ')';
}

}
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I really think you need to read this: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/behavioralseparation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend creating a class definition to set the opacity for elements. Then, in your javascript, you would only need to write:

```
document.getElementById(ba[i]).className = "opacityClassName".
```

In your CSS, your opacityClassName style definition can look something like this:

```
.opacityClassName {
    filter: alpha(opacity:0.5);
    KHTMLOpacity: 0.5;
    MozOpacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity:.50;
    -ms-filter:"alpha(opacity=50)";
    -moz-opacity:.50;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity:.50;
}
```

In this way, you don't have to worry about syntax like:

```
document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.ms-filter
```

not working.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

The important part: "IE8 uses a new notation: `-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";`"

Also, Internet Explorer (6 and 8) seems to think that the element must have `width` explicitly set, before it can be transparent. Weird. The above link *does* set the width with CSS, but doesn't mention this strange requirement.

(although you didn't specifically ask about it, I'd recommend using jQuery for this type of tasks - it makes such effects much easier to work with, see e.g. here: http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/ )

Comment: Jquery is too much for me to handle right now :) gave it a quick try but that didn't work. I am slightly confused, this does not appear to work:
document.getElementById(ba[i]).style.ms-filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=' + value*10 + ')';

Comment: Try `ms_filter` or msFilter`: JavaScript treats `-` as an operator.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery. I'm aware that this is *the* cliché answer, but in this case, it's spot on: it handles the browser quirks for you, automagically.

Observe example:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="5" ID='links'>
<ul id="navlist">
    <li id="active"><a href="#" id="a">Apie įmonę</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="b">Naujienos</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="c">Kainynai</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="d">Aktyvaus laisvalaikio priemonės</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="e">Servisas</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="f">Akcijos</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="g">Karjera</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="h">Galerija</a>|</li>
    <li><a href="#" ID="i">Naudota technika</a></li>
</ul>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js">
</script><!-- load jQuery -->
<script>
// run when the document is loaded
$(document).ready(function(){

    // give each link under #navlist opacity, unless cursor is over it
    $('#navlist a').mouseover(function(){
        var current = this;
            // run the following for each matching element
        $('#navlist a').each(function(index,element){
            if (element != current) {
                // handles browser quirks for us
                    $(element).css('opacity',0.5);
            }
        });
    });

    // remove the opacity
    $('#navlist a').mouseout(function(event){
        $('#navlist a').each(function(index,element){
            $(element).css('opacity',1);
        });
    });
});

</script>
```

Works cross-browser (Opera, Chromium, Midori, Firefox, IE6 *and* IE8), with less code, gets the job done. Time spent: 15 minutes.